# override method of Grails plugin bean

Tags: spring, grails, groovy, spring-security

The Spring Security plugin provides a bean named 'springSecurityService' of type `grails.plugins.springsecurity.SpringSecurityService`. I need to override the `getCurrentUser` method of this service.

I first tried to do it using extension

```
class CustomSecurityService extends SpringSecurityService {

    @Override
    Object getCurrentUser() {
        // my implementation uses methods from the parent class
    }
}
```

To replace the bean defined by the plugin with an instance of the class above I added the following to `resources.groovy`

```
springSecurityService(CustomSpringSecurityService)
```

But this didn't work because none of the dependencies of `SpringSecurityService` (the class I'm extending) are set so I get NullPointerExceptions. The reason these dependencies are not set is because there's no longer a spring bean of type `SpringSecurityService`

So, I then turned to delegation:

```
import grails.plugins.springsecurity.SpringSecurityService as PluginSpringSecurityService

class CustomSpringSecurityService {

    @Autowired @Delegate
    PluginSpringSecurityService pluginSpringSecurityService

    Object getCurrentUser() {
        // my implementation uses methods from pluginSpringSecurityService
    }
}
```

I then defined two beans in `resources.groovy`

```
springSecurityService(CustomSpringSecurityService)
pluginSpringSecurityService(grails.plugins.springsecurity.SpringSecurityService)
```

In this second attempt, I again want the bean named 'springSecurityService' to refer to `CustomSpringSecurityService`, but I also need a bean of type `grails.plugins.springsecurity.SpringSecurityService`, because my implememtation of `getCurrentUser` use some other methods of that bean.

However, I again found that the dependencies of `pluginSpringSecurityService` are not being set. Is there an easier way to override a method of a bean provided by a plugin in a context that is subject to dependency injection?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Go back to subclassing and redefining the bean in `resources.groovy`, but satisfy the dependencies. They're auto-injected by name but all listed, so add them explicitly to your redefinition:

```
springSecurityService(CustomSpringSecurityService) {
   authenticationTrustResolver = ref('authenticationTrustResolver')
   grailsApplication = ref('grailsApplication')
   passwordEncoder = ref('passwordEncoder')
   objectDefinitionSource = ref('objectDefinitionSource')
   userDetailsService = ref('userDetailsService')
   userCache = ref('userCache')
}
```

Comment: Thanks Burt, that works. Do you know why the dependencies of SpringSecurityService weren't being autowired when I tried the delegation approach?