# Grails Mail Plugin: Absolute Path to View

Tags: email, templates, grails

I need to store my email templates in a location that can be edited without redeploying the grails application.  I'm looking for a way to render these templates as views for the mail plugin based on an absolute path.  Currently both the built in 'view' and the grails render method are based on the grails-app/views location.

UPDATE: For now, I'm going to use the SimpleTemplateEngine and just feed the string into the body.  I'd still like to know if there is a more "grails" way of pulling this off.

Comment: I've not done this personally, but if you're ok externalizing all your GSPs I think you can set `grails.gsp.view.dir` in your Config.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't want to externalize all of them.

Comment: Create a plug-in for your mail functionality and use `grails.gsp.view.dir` in the plug-in, using the default for your main app?

Comment: Config files in plugins are ignored when bundled in the WAR.  It will only use the application's config file.

Comment: I took a look through the mail-plugin code, and thought you could possibly do what you wanted making a custom extension to `MailMessageContentRenderer` and overriding `getTemplate()` to use the `createTemplate(File)` method of `groovyPagesTemplateEngine`.  Seems like it should work and I played around with it for a little bit, but haven't been able to get it to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not working yet, but this question doesn't seem to be getting many answers so I don't think having this here is too distracting.

Here's what I tried in resources.groovy:

```
mailMessageContentRenderer(gregg.stackoverflow.CustomPathMailMessageContentRenderer) {
    groovyPagesTemplateEngine = ref('groovyPagesTemplateEngine')
    groovyPagesUriService = ref('groovyPagesUriService')
    grailsApplication = ref('grailsApplication')
}
```

If you look through mail-plugin, there are two beans `mailMessageBuidlerFactory` and `mailMessageContentRenderer` defined.  Based on what [other people have done](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7132679/override-method-of-grails-plugin-bean) I really expected this to override the renderer and let you customize the behavior.  When I put in logging to see the class of the `mailService.mailMessageBuilderFactory.mailMessageContentRenderer` it is the custom one so wiring appears to work correctly.  I created the following custom renderer:

```
    package gregg.stackoverflow

    import org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.ConfigurationHolder

    class CustomPathMailMessageContentRenderer extends grails.plugin.mail.MailMessageContentRenderer {


    @Override
    protected createTemplate(String templateName, String controllerName, String pluginName) {
        def gspOverride = ConfigurationHolder.config.mailtemplate.gsp.dir
        println "Custom one!"
        if (!gspOverride) {
            return super.createTemplate(templateName, controllerName, pluginName)
        }
        else {

            def contextPath = gspOverride + templateName +".gsp"

            def gspFile = new File(contextPath)

            def template = groovyPagesTemplateEngine.createTemplate(gspFile)

            if (!template) {
                if (pluginName) {
                    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Could not locate email view ${templateName} in plugin [$pluginName]")
                } else {
                    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Could not locate mail body ${templateName}. Is it in a plugin? If so you must pass the plugin name in the [plugin] variable")
                }
            }

            return template
        }
    }
}
```

Also, I added a property to `Config.groovy` to indicate the GSP directory called `mailtemplate.gsp.dir` that would switch between default functionality and the custom directory.

But println statement I put in there doesn't display.  I was messing with this as a distraction after a very long day, so it's possible that my brain was just fried but I won't have time to figure it out today so sorry for posting non-working, very unpolished code.  Hope you figure it out.

**Upate**

Okay, because I'm OCD once I get started on things like this and can live for long periods on caffeine and no food, I got this working over lunch... sort of, most of the way... :-) You have to use GSP views but I'm not sure templates will work (I'm guessing including templates in your GSP views will not work either).  So the `sendMail` calls look like this:

```
mailService.sendMail {
        to "name@domain.tld"
        body (view:"/test", model:[name:"Chris"])
        // subject, from, etc still work
}
```

So with all the above code and the line:

`mailtemplate.gsp.dir=C:\\gsptest`

and a GSP called `C:\gsptest\test.gsp` I was able to successfully send myself an email from an externalized GSP.